# Running the command 'firefox -CreateProfile sarah' in python

Tags: python

I need to know how to run the command 'firefox -CreateProfile sarah' in python.

```py
import os
os.system('firefox -CreateProfile sarah')
```

the error is

`'firefox' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: On which OS are you running it?

Comment: I fixed a few typos in your question, and put the error message into a grey box-- though I'm not sure that's the verbatim error message, or a summary.  Please feel free to edit the question.

Also, when you post a question like this, it would help to give more detail on which kind of system you're using, like Unix (linux, macOS X, etc.), Windows, or another operating system.   The problem you are trying to fix depends on system you are using. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should be add firefox path installation into windows `PATH`

Comment: i add it .the command run perfectly in the command prompt but not in python

Comment: This change must be made